# In azure databricks gen2, I am trying to modify value of column in pandas dataframe. My code is working fine in gen1 but in gen2 it is throwing error

Tags: pandas, azure-databricks, pyspark-pandas

```
data_2['col1'] = np.where((df1.year.astype(int) == 2021) & (df1.col1_y.notna()), df1.col1_y, data_2.col1)
```

This is my original working code in Gen1, but it isgiving following error in gen2.

```
PandasNotImplementedError: The method `pd.Series.__iter__()` is not implemented. If you want to collect your data as an NumPy array, use 'to_numpy()' instead.
```

I tried adding .to_numpy() but I got another error which is below.

```
data_2['col1'] = np.where((df1.year.to_numpy().astype(int) == 2021) & (df1.col1_y.notna()), df1.col1_y, data_2.col1)

AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute '_internal'
```

I could not understand why is it looking for _internal.
Could someone help in resolution of this error?

I tried

```
data_2['col1'] = np.where((df1.year.astype(int) == 2021) & (df1.col1_y.notna()), df1.col1_y, data_2.col1)
```

this code first and then

```
data_2['col1'] = np.where((df1.year.to_numpy().astype(int) == 2021) & (df1.col1_y.notna()), df1.col1_y, data_2.col1)
```

this code.

The value in column col1 should be as per condition mentioned in code, but instead I am getting error.

Comment: Here the `df1` is your pandas dataframe?

Comment: Yes, df1 is Pandas dataframe.

Comment: what are the numpy and pandas version using?
Do 
`import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

print("Pandas version:", pd.__version__)
print("NumPy version:", np.__version__)`

Comment: In gen1 the version is
Pandas version: 0.24.2
NumPy version: 1.16.2

In gen2 the version is 
Pandas version: 1.3.4
NumPy version: 1.20.3

Comment: It is working fine in pandas dataframe but getting above error using pyspark pandas.

Comment: Yes, I am importing pyspark.pandas in gen2.

Comment: Added solution check it

Comment: Solution is working fine. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Convert pyspark-pandas to pandas dataframe and execute your code, then it will work successfully.

```
df1 = df1.to_pandas()
data_2 = data_2.to_pandas()
data_2['col1'] = np.where((df1.year.astype(int) == 2021) & (df1.col1_y.notna()), df1.col1_y, data_2.col1)
data_2
```

[image]